# Explaining Applicative functor in categorical terms - monoidal functors

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory, functional-programming, ct.category-theory

I'd like to understand `Applicative` in terms of category theory.

The [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html) for `Applicative` says that it's *a strong lax monoidal functor*.

First, Wikipedia page about [monoidal functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_functor) says that a monoidal functor is either *lax* or *strong*. So it seems to me that either one of the sources is wrong, or they use the terms differently. Can anybody explain that?

Second, what are the monoidal categories of which `Applicative` are monoidal functors? I assume that the functors are endo-functors on the standard Haskell category (objects = types, morphisms = functions), but I have no idea what is the monoidal structure on this category.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There are actually two uses of the word "strength" in play here.

- A *strong endofunctor* $F : C \to C$ over a monoidal category $(C, \otimes, I)$ is one which comes with a natural transformation $\sigma : A \otimes F(B) \to F(A \otimes B)$, satisfying some coherence conditions with respect to the associator which I will gloss over. This condition is sometimes also pronounced "$F$ has a strength".
- A *lax monoidal functor* $F : C \to D$ is a functor between two monoidal categories $(C, \otimes, I)$ and $(D, \oplus, J)$ with natural transformations $\phi : F(A) \oplus F(B) \to F(A \otimes B)$ and $i : J \to F(I)$, again satisfying a coherence condition with respect to the associators.
- A *strong monoidal functor* $F : C \to D$ is one in which $\phi$ and $i$ are natural isomorphisms. That is, $F(A \otimes B) \simeq F(A) \oplus F(B)$, with $\phi$ and its inverse describing the isomorphism.

An applicative functor, in the sense of Haskell programs, is a *lax monoidal endofunctor with a strength*, with the monoidal structure in question being the Cartesian products. So this is why you get the paradoxical-sounding term "strong lax monoidal functor".

As an aside, in a Cartesian closed category, $F$ having a strength is equivalent to the existence of a natural transformation $\mathrm{map} : (A \Rightarrow B) \to (F(A) \Rightarrow F(B))$. That is, having a strength means that the functorial action is definable as a higher-order function in the programming language.

Finally, if you're interested in the type theory of Haskell-style applicative functors, [I've just blogged about it.](http://semantic-domain.blogspot.com/2012/08/a-computational-lambda-calculus-for.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do I understand it correctly that all instances of `Functor` have a strength (WRT product), simply because they're defined using `fmap` inside the language? Also, what puzzles me that your definition of $\phi$ and $i$ is reversed compared to both your blog post and [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_functor#Definition) - is it a typo? I tried to define `pure` using `i` as `pure' = \v -> fmap (\() -> v) (i ())`, which clearly needs `i :: (Applicative f) => () -> f ()`.

Comment: I had a typo in this answer -- now fixed. And yes, all instances of `Functor` are strong (wrt product).

Comment: Could you please also elaborate where Monad stands? If I understand right it's a monoidal endofunctor as well.

Comment: @egdmitry _Monoidal_, not _monadal_. This means the we deal with an endofunctor of a monoidal category (in this case $\operatorname{Hask}$ being monoidal relative to cartesian product, i.e. pairs).

Comment: May I propose to use the word *strengthy* to avoid clash of notation with "strong"? It's a Scottish (so particularly spot-on here) dialectal variation of "strong", first used in Wycliffe's Bible.

Answer (score 4):

To understand Applicative, as induced by a monad, I want to point out the following construction:

The Yoneda lemma implies that there is an isomorphism between $FA$ and $\mathrm{nat}(\mathrm{Hom}(A,B),FB)$. In the category of Haskell types, this is the mapping
$$a\mapsto\left(g\mapsto F(g)(a)\right)$$ 
of type
$$FA\to B^A\to FB.$$ 
Evaluating at $FA$, then applying the functors arrow map to the resulting function - if the components of the natural transformation make sense as arrows - and abstracting $FA$ again, we obtain a mapping of type 
$$FA\to F\,B^A\to FFB.$$ 
Now if the functor comes with a monadic 'join', mapping from $FFB$ to $FB$, and if we switch around the lambda abstractions and thus the first two argument slots, we can we can obtain a function of type 
$$F\,B^A\to FA\to FB,$$ 
which one denotes by <*>. 
(This is also what you get via $\mathrm{LiftM2\ id}$ in Haskell.)